# Bootstrap carousel not cycling back to first slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Looking for some help here folks. I'm getting some really strange behavior with my Bootstrap 3 carousel and wordpress (on my local). I have four image slides, and all four display properly and slide correctly. 
However, when I get to the last slide and advance, instead of cycling back to the first slide, the carousel adds another slide, that has no content, just the Prev and Next arrows. If I advance forward at this point, the next slide is a single, thin block of color. 
At this point, I can't get back to the actual slides regardless of moving forward or back. I'm at a loss, and ready to hasan chop my computer. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
<img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RMTide/images/image1.jpg" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h2>Boys swimming win division championship</h2>
<p>By the time the Division I championships started on the morning of February 1, the RM boys swim team...<a href="#">Read More...</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RMTide/images/image2.jpg" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h2>RM poms places on top</h2>
<p>One hour later in Rockville, the Rockets' poms team sat hand in hand and took a deep breath...<a href="#">Read More...</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RMTide/images/image3.jpg" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h2>O'Malley voices opposition to weed legalization</h2>
<p>The legalization of marijuana has become a point of interest...<a href="#">Read More...     </a></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RMTide/images/image4.jpg" alt="">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h2>Down to the Wire:</h2>
<p>Seven days until the state championship...<a href="#">Read More...</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is my script
    
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    }); 
    
Any help much MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue (locally and remotely).  I'm using the **Roots Theme** and basically copied the **Carousel** source from the **Bootstrap** site example to start with.  I found that WordPress was inserting open ended **P tags** in the source, so I ran the **Carousel HTML** code through a web based **HTML** compressor (**minifier**).  Re-pasted back into **WP** and it was fixed.